# flow in mobx-state-tree calls only the first async method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

Here is the code of an action in my store:

```
load: flow(function*(titleId: string) {
  self.title = yield Api.Get(titleId);
  self.matrices = yield Api.ListMatrix();
})
```

All the Api methods return `Promise<T>`.

When I call `await Store.load()` only **Api.Get** is called, not flowing to the next Api call. When I comment out the first line, **Api.ListMatrix** is called. So I guess, instead of automatically flowing from one yield to the next, execution stops at the first yield statement.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not going to the next `yield` statement probably there is some kind of error with the `api`.

Also, how are you passing the `titleId` to the `Store.load()`?

In the end try wrapping the `yield Api.Get(titleId)` in a `try/catch` block and see what happens.